Do nitrocellulose finishes ever reach a state of inertness?
I’ve never had a guitar with a nitro finish, all my guitars have stands or hangers with some kind of rubber grip.
I just bought a neck which has a nitro finish, it was built to order, so the finish is only a couple of weeks old.
I’ve read enough to know that the finish will react with rubber, so I plan to do something about that, as far as its stand goes.
But my question is about the curing of nitro cellulose finishes. Do they ever reach a state of inertness? If so, roughly how long after application is that reached?
The online discourse doesn’t seem to be clear on this, so I’m hoping to get a definitive answer on the subject.

Never had a problem, but I only have older guitars hanging in the studio. Best bet is to use some plastic sheet on the hanger if you're concerned.

The rule of thumb with nitrocellulose guitar finishes is six months from freshly painted to fully cured.
Variables of local temperatures, humidity, and barometric pressure aside, six months is a reliable figure.
A side note, all my guitars hang from the wall on the foam rubber covered hangers, and I have never once had a problem with bleed over or staining.
But then again, I play my guitars quite frequently.
